# “Prev”/“next” triangles rendered as Emojis on iOS devices

Tags: discussion, feature-request, mobile-web, mobile-safari

In the (default) Safari browser on an iPhone the "prev" and "next" characters in the links at the bottom of
the questions page are rendered as Emojis, which looks quite ugly:

[image]

The HTML source contains the characters

```
 ◀  U+25C0   BLACK LEFT-POINTING TRIANGLE
 ▶  U+25B6   BLACK RIGHT-POINTING TRIANGLE
```

On iOS devices, these characters are rendered as an "Emoji variant"
and appear as a white triangle on a blue background.

This was already observed in [Unicode characters being drawn differently in iOS5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8335724/unicode-characters-being-drawn-differently-in-ios5) and was (controversially) discussed in the
[Apple Developer Forums: How to disable emoji in a UILabel?](https://devforums.apple.com/message/487463#487463)
(requires Developer login).

I observed this with iOS 8 on an iPhone, but as I understand it, the
same happens on all iOS devices since iOS 5.

This is an iOS problem and not a Safari problem. It does not happen in the "mobile view" in Safari on OS X:

[image]

As noticed in an answer to [Unicode characters being drawn differently in iOS5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8335724/unicode-characters-being-drawn-differently-in-ios5), one can append the Unicode "variation selector" U+FE0E (HTML: `&#xFE0E;`) to suppress this Emoji substitution.

Finally, my question:

- Should this considered as an iOS/Apple problem (and no action is
  necessary)?
- Or would it be possible to append the Unicode variation selector to
  those triangle characters to achieve a nice output on iOS devices?
  (But I have no idea if *all* current mobile browsers recognize the
  variation selector.)
- Or could the left/right triangle characters be replaced by something
  else so that this problem is avoided?

**EDIT:** Motivated by the comments I'll make this a
*feature request* now:

- Please append the Unicode variation selector U+FE0E (HTML: `&#xFE0E;`)
  to the triangle characters in the navigation links, to prevent them
  from being rendered as Emojis on iOS devices.

**EDIT 2:** The same problem was observed (and fixed) here:
[Why is the mod diamond red for question titles in the iOS app? ♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223155/).

Comment: Might want to ask about disabling this on [apple.se]; I can't imagine wanting this on any site.

Comment: @Shog9: Sorry, I don't get what you mean. I it is known *how* this can be disabled (by appending a Unicode variation selector, as I wrote in the question). My question was if Stack Exchange should change its HTML code and add the variation selector to those triangle characters.

Comment: I think I reported this already when the new UI was launched, but can't find it. Nevermind. This should be fixed!

Comment: It should most definitely be fixed.

Comment: @Pat if it was downvoted without answers, it might have been cleaned up by automatic process. Check the "deleted recent questions". :)

Comment: Jup. Did that too. Really :)

Answer (score 3):

This is still a problem with iOS 14. I do not like the workarounds using the Unicode variation selector as I am referring to it in a Javascript method which flips between forward and downward arrows for a custom hide/show (which is why I want to fix it as the downward arrow is normal on the phone).

My hack/kludge is to use the Black Right-pointing **Pointer** instead. This has a similar appearance to the triangle:

[image: rendering of triangles and pointers on iPhone]

[Screen grab from iPhoneXS under iOS 14.4]

Comment: I know it's late in the day, but I thought I'd post in case my kludge is useful to anyone with the same problem who finds this question in the same way as I did.

Answer (score 1):

This is occurring because these arrows do not exist in the font you are using and iOS is falling back on its emoji font. To resolve this problem, include a symbol-friendly font like Hiragino Mincho ProN in your font stack. i.e.

```
font-family: Helvetica, Arial, "Hiragino Mincho ProN", sans-serif;
```

See also this answer in Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8412044/672086

Comment: so you're telling everyone to install a userstyle/userscript to change their SO font?

Comment: Is this even still an issue? This is an old question from when SE had a mobile view. The mobile view was [removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367609/deprecating-our-mobile-views) and responsive theme took over. In the responsive theme I don't see symbols, but instead words are used (e.g. "Prev", "Next"). See screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLDRM.png

Comment: This is still a general recurring issue with font display on iOS that I have encountered several times, which is why I posted this answer. It is not an issue for Stack Overflow or Stack Exchange, neither of which seem to have been mentioned in the body of the original question. I do appreciate that the OP was talking about SE from his comment on 20 Jul 2015, but I am clearly not the only one thinking he was asking a more general question.