# Why is the mod diamond (♦) red in Android?

Tags: support, android-app, moderators, android

Related: [Why is the mod diamond red for question titles in the iOS app? ♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223155/why-is-the-mod-diamond-red-for-question-titles-in-the-ios-app)

I noticed that the mod diamond shows up red. I'm pretty sure it wasn't red not long ago. Has anything changed recently?

[image: IMG:]

I'm on:

- Android 6, Nexus 5
- Stack Exchange v. `1.0.73`

---

This is also true for the mobile view in Chrome (`45.0.2454.94`):

[image: IMG:]

But not in Firefox (where it matches the surrounding text, or is black):

[image: IMG:] [image: IMG:]

Comment: It's black for me in the Android app.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom like [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/256592/270345)?

Comment: Yes, like that one. Just saying I can't reproduce your issue.

Comment: It is in celebration of the Blood Moon, for it is then that we ***rise and reclaim what is ours.***

Comment: @Emrakul time to set about finding things to reclaim, then. :D

Comment: Also, Android 6? Damn, Lolipop didn't get any breathing room.

Comment: Also, Also, there's an entire stack for VI? jfc.

Comment: @cde Nope. Been waiting for permission control for too long. :/ Yep: [vi.se], and also for [emacs.se].

Comment: @muru gee, I wonder if I can get a stack for Nano started.

Comment: @cde won't hurt to try. :D

Comment: Confirm repro'd on Android 6, and only since Android 6, including any matching emoji on most apps (e.g. Chrome).

Comment: This isn't really a bug, it's more a difference between Android versions / skins :(

Comment: Reproduced in Android 7.1.1 in both Chrome and the default browser (the one called "Browser").  Is there a fix or a workaround?

Answer (score 7):

Checking on my android device (Kitkat 4.x, Samsung), on Browser (Chromium) and Chrome, it's a Black Diamond that matches the Diamond Emoji available. Checking on an older Froyo 2.x android device, Browser (Froyo Webkit) that has color-less emoji, it still matches the plain emoji available.

[As the related question for IOS shows, it matches the Emoji of the system.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223155/why-is-the-mod-diamond-red-for-question-titles-in-the-ios-app)

Firefox of course, doesn't use Webkit or anything based on it, so how it handles Unicode characters can differ.

Comment: Firefox shows yet another behaviour. Does it use its own emojis?

Comment: @muru I'd chock that up to Firefox using it's own code based on Mozilla gecko web engine, unlike Android native web view and chrome using webkit (or Blink, based on webkit).

Comment: Probably. That might explain Opera Mini (New) also showing the same behaviour as Firefox. Though why the same behaviour.. O.o

Answer (score 5):

The diamond turned red for me when I upgraded my Nexus 9 to Android 6.0. It's red in Chrome:

[image]

And in the mobile app:

[image]

It wasn't like this before Android 6, so I'm going to chalk this bug up to it.

Comment: Looks orange to me. Not that it really matters. :)