# Moderator's diamond is not displayed anywhere except post's body (android app)

Tags: bug, status-norepro, design, android-app

I noticed in a duplicate banner that the diamond symbol of Community is not showing properly:

> [image: closed question]

Same in the users list:

> [image: user list]

After installing SwiftKey keyboard, some of emojis are not displayed:

> [image: swiftkey]

I can see diamond in related link, but not in the title:

> [image: diamond question]

- App Version: 1.0.89
- Device Manufacturer: LGE
- Device Model: LG-H860
- OS Version: 6.0.1 (1612001239cf4)

Comment: No repro for me. Looks like your OS is missing the required font.

Comment: Same as @ShadowWizard. I do know that on the web interface, the diamond is a character and not an image. I would suspect the same is true on the Android app and that your fonts don't have the required character.

Comment: Interesting test you can perform is using Chrome app on your device and check if you can see the diamond symbol of moderators.

Comment: @ShadowWizard in Chrome on the phone I see red diamond for moderators.

Comment: Weird... dunno then.

Comment: it's definitely a font issue, that square it's replaced with is the .notdef glyph you see when the character doesn't exist in the font. Have you changed the system font? I'm assuming the app is using the custom font which doesn't have the diamond and the mobile site is using the normal system font.

Comment: @Cai I tried to change font but no effect for all of preinstalled in my phone (Roboto, LG Smart, KindGothic, Friend, Travel, Yoyo).

Comment: Very strange. Maybe the diamond is rendered in a specific (separate to the rest of the app) font which your system should, but doesn't have.

Comment: @Cai long shot, but maybe it's dependant on emoji? alex, can you follow [this article](http://mashable.com/2014/06/18/emoji-on-android/#QIv4SJmTEkq0) please and see if you have emoji supported, and if not, install? Edit: not so long shot... looks like the android app is using [Black Diamond Suit Emoji](https://www.emojibase.com/emoji/2666/blackdiamondsuit) to show the diamond. :/

Comment: @Sha the red diamond is visible in Chrome (which should be the emoji) so it looks like it is on the system, just not in the app... I'm stumped.

Comment: You can see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267504/why-is-the-mod-diamond-red-in-android) that the app and Chrome should use the same diamond (unless it's been changed since then of course)

Comment: @Cai maybe Chrome app is using the system font diamond, or smart enough to detect when there's no emoji support and replace it with "plain" symbol... dunno.

Comment: @alexolut can you see the diamond in title of [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267504/why-is-the-mod-diamond-red-in-android)?

Comment: @ShadowWizard added info to question body.

Comment: Actually it was @Cai who asked. Well, it's just getting weirder...

Comment: It certainly is weird.. since some of your emoji are showing the same issue I'd assume it's an android problem not a SE specific issue. Not sure though.

Comment: @ShadowWizard seems font settings in title and body are different for app.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem was solved after updating Android version to - 7.0 (1635123498b3d). Picture of user list to confirm:

> [image: user diamond]