# Why isn't my edit visible?

Tags: bug, edits, revisions-list

I edited [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/286729/307988) to show smaller screenshots.

When I came back to the question, my edit was gone:

> [image]

It still says I edited the question:

> [image]

My edit is still the most recent edit in the revision history. But it includes some text changes *I didn't make*, so it looks like it was rolled in to someone elses edit... or something:

> [image]

I hit the [edit] link and my edit is already there:

> [image]

I've viewed the question on a few devices on different connections so it's not a local cache issue my end. I thought maybe it was a caching issue but I've waited 30 minutes now and the edit previous to mine is still visible. I even tried re-saving the edit with no luck, so... What's going on?

Comment: That's probably a bug, result of a very rare edit conflict where both editors have 2k rep , so none of the edits have been fully rejected.

Comment: Yeh I assumed there was some conflict going on. It's strange that it wouldn't let me re-submit the edit—I guess the edit was saved everywhere except the actual post body and it didn't recognise it as a new edit (I'm guessing it would have saved if I tried to submit a *different* edit).

Comment: Yup, that's what I think as well. Hope a dev will come over and be able to dig deeper.

Comment: t's definitely an inconsistency, not sure if it's a bug... maybe it's intentional?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens huh?