# Font size for comment button is too large in Android app

Tags: bug, design, android-app

Font size for comment button is too large in Android app

> [image: comment button]

- App Version: 1.0.95
- Device Manufacturer: LGE
- Device Model: LM-G710
- OS Version: 8.0.0 (181662202158b.FGN)

Comment: No repro. Probably something on your end? Did you install anything that can mess with fonts?

Comment: @ShadowWizard this makes me recall my old [bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/286729/339911). Now I'm on new phone, and again here is the issue with font. Looks like I need to wait Android 9 update to fix :)

Comment: Actually, much higher chance that the app will stop working in android 9. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the system (preinstalled) font or its size may fix or even aggravate the issue:

> [image: fit]

> [image: more buggy]